# Error HE0046. Rider fails to install iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, rider

When trying to debug an iOS application in Rider (macOS) I get this error message in the run window.

```
error HE0046: Failed to install the app 'com.company.name' on the device 'iOS 13.5 (17F61) - iPhone 8': Failed to install the requested application
```

If I switch to Visual Studio it works fine. I am unable to find any more information regarding this error or why it is occuring. Anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Maybe this link can help you? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/591502/error-he0046-failed-to-install-the-app-xxx.html

Comment: @xtmq None of my projects in the solution have an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible ways to understand what is going on during deploy - read msbuild logs.

Go to Rider Preferences: `Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolset and Build` and enable this logs there:

[image: Settings]

Then deploy the app and go to this folder and read msbuild logs. Probably there is a specific error there.

Also you can compare these logs to visual studio log. Anyway anytime you can fire an issue in Rider issue tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=Rider

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by re cloning my repo.